# Post Meta rows from other types being added to DB regardless of post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I have 3-4 custom post types in my wordpress site. Each one has some unique post meta fields I create and update using meta boxes.

In looking in the database during development I'm noticing that every post meta field being used for all custom types is being added for every time I add a post regardless of post type.

So if i add a "Team" post type, it adds a row for every meta field for Team custom post type and all the meta fields for the Person custom post type as well (the person ones have blank values but it's still taking up rows in the database).

Why is this happening? I'd rather prevent the excess rows since I'm going to have a large amount of data.

Comment: What's your code?

Comment: Please post the function that you're hooking onto the post saving that saves the meta data.

Comment: I guess an `if` can solve your problem, without seing your code is impossible to say where this `if` goes..